# Getting a span's attr within nested div

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

New to **scraping** here.
My question is pretty straight forward, am trying to get the value `data-value` from span class "DFlfde SwHCTb". However I'm getting undefined return. What's the mistake I have made in the following code?

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=sgd+myr&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiStvfn5ozoAhVWH7cAHQJZCpwQBSgAegQIDRAm&biw=960&bih=746';

axios(url)
  .then(response => {
    const html = response.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    console.log($('span.DFlfde.SwHCTb').attr('data-value'));
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

When printing only `console.log($('span.DFlfde.SwHCTb'));`

```
initialize {
  options: {
    withDomLvl1: true,
    normalizeWhitespace: false,
    xml: false,
    decodeEntities: true
  },
  _root: initialize {
    '0': {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
      children: [Array],
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null
    },
    options: {
      withDomLvl1: true,
      normalizeWhitespace: false,
      xml: false,
      decodeEntities: true
    },
    length: 1,
    _root: [Circular]
  },
  length: 0,
  prevObject: initialize {
    '0': {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
      children: [Array],
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null
    },
    options: {
      withDomLvl1: true,
      normalizeWhitespace: false,
      xml: false,
      decodeEntities: true
    },
    length: 1,
    _root: [Circular]
  }
}
```

Comment: Those classes are dynamic and may be getting added late. You probably need Puppeteer for this.

Comment: Indeed they are, I tried to read value from $ and realized the class method is different from inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector seems fine. Try adding a user agent string:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const url = "<Your URL>";
const ua =
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 9; S40Lite) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.91 Mobile Safari/537.36"; // may need to rotate if this one doesn't work

axios
  .get(url, {headers: {"User-Agent": ua}})
  .then(({data: html}) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($("span.DFlfde.SwHCTb").attr("data-value")); // => 3.280947958
  })
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```